# Intersection between Geopandas Polygon and Shapely LineString

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, intersection, geopandas, shapely

Let us say we have the following Square Shape as Geopandas DataFrame

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString, LinearRing, Point, Polygon

polygon_geom = Polygon(zip([0,1,1,0], [0,0,1,1]))
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
polygon = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs=crs, geometry=[polygon_geom])
```

> Note: The polygon I'm working with is a shape file imported to
> Geopandas, and for the sake of example I have created a geopanda
> dataframe for the polygon.

I have another LineString using Shapely

```
Point1 = Point(0,1)
Point2 = Point(2,0)
line = LineString([Point1,Point2])
```

I need to find the intersection points between the `polygon` and the `line`. Expected result to be two points `(1,0)` and `(1,0.5)`

I have tried intersection method and overly but did not succeed with that. I would really appreciate the support and hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your particular case, you can get the geometry of the polygon as:-

```
poly = polygon.geometry.values[0]
```

This checks if the `line` and `poly` are intersecting:-

```
line.intersects(poly)
```

It returns `True`.
So we go ahead with:-

```
line.intersection(poly).xy
```

and get

(array('d', [0.0, 1.0]), array('d', [1.0, 0.5]))

as the result.

Comment: Thanks that worked. What if I have a geopandas Series of LineString? This will return a series of LineString or Point. How to get the points only?